# How to fix these coding

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, compiler-errors, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow.js

```
{"modelTopology":{"class_name":"Model","config":{"name":"model4","layers":[{"name":"conv2d_1_input","class_name":"InputLayer","config":{"batch_input_shape":[null,43,232,1],"dtype":"float32","sparse":false,"name":"conv2d_1_input"},"inbound_nodes":[]},{"name":"conv2d_1","class_name":"Conv2D","config":{"filters":8,"kernel_initializer":{"class_name":"VarianceScaling","config":{"scale":1,"mode":"fan_avg","distribution":"uniform","seed":null}},"kernel_regularizer":null,"kernel_constraint":null,"kernel_size":[2,8],"strides":[1,1],"padding":"valid","data_format":"channels_last","dilation_rate":[1,1],"activation":"relu","use_bias":true,"bias_initializer":{"class_name":"Zeros","config":{}},"bias_regularizer":null,"activity_regularizer":null,"bias_constraint":null,"name":"conv2d_1","trainable":false,"batch_input_shape":[null,43,232,1],"dtype":"float32"},"inbound_nodes":[[["conv2d_1_input",0,0,{}]]]},{"name":"max_pooling2d_1","class_name":"MaxPooling2D","config":{"pool_size":[2,2],"padding":"valid","strides":[2,2],"data_format":"channels_last","name":"max_pooling2d_1","trainable":false},"inbound_nodes":[[["conv2d_1",0,0,{}]]]},{"name":"conv2d_2","class_name":"Conv2D","config":{"filters":32,"kernel_initializer":{"class_name":"VarianceScaling","config":{"scale":1,"mode":"fan_avg","distribution":"uniform","seed":null}},"kernel_regularizer":null,"kernel_constraint":null,"kernel_size":[2,4],"strides":[1,1],"padding":"valid","data_format":"channels_last","dilation_rate":[1,1],"activation":"relu","use_bias":true,"bias_initializer":{"class_name":"Zeros","config":{}},"bias_regularizer":null,"activity_regularizer":null,"bias_constraint":null,"name":"conv2d_2","trainable":false},"inbound_nodes":[[["max_pooling2d_1",0,0,{}]]]},{"name":"max_pooling2d_2","class_name":"MaxPooling2D","config":{"pool_size":[2,2],"padding":"valid","strides":[2,2],"data_format":"channels_last","name":"max_pooling2d_2","trainable":false},"inbound_nodes":[[["conv2d_2",0,0,{}]]]},{"name":"conv2d_3","class_name":"Conv2D","config":{"filters":32,"kernel_initializer":{"class_name":"VarianceScaling","config":{"scale":1,"mode":"fan_avg","distribution":"uniform","seed":null}},"kernel_regularizer":null,"kernel_constraint":null,"kernel_size":[2,4],"strides":[1,1],"padding":"valid","data_format":"channels_last","dilation_rate":[1,1],"activation":"relu","use_bias":true,"bias_initializer":{"class_name":"Zeros","config":{}},"bias_regularizer":null,"activity_regularizer":null,"bias_constraint":null,"name":"conv2d_3","trainable":false},"inbound_nodes":[[["max_pooling2d_2",0,0,{}]]]},{"name":"max_pooling2d_3","class_name":"MaxPooling2D","config":{"pool_size":[2,2],"padding":"valid","strides":[2,2],"data_format":"channels_last","name":"max_pooling2d_3","trainable":false},"inbound_nodes":[[["conv2d_3",0,0,{}]]]},{"name":"conv2d_4","class_name":"Conv2D","config":{"filters":32,"kernel_initializer":{"class_name":"VarianceScaling","config":{"scale":1,"mode":"fan_avg","distribution":"uniform","seed":null}},"kernel_regularizer":null,"kernel_constraint":null,"kernel_size":[2,4],"strides":[1,1],"padding":"valid","data_format":"channels_last","dilation_rate":[1,1],"activation":"relu","use_bias":true,"bias_initializer":{"class_name":"Zeros","config":{}},"bias_regularizer":null,"activity_regularizer":null,"bias_constraint":null,"name":"conv2d_4","trainable":false},"inbound_nodes":[[["max_pooling2d_3",0,0,{}]]]},{"name":"max_pooling2d_4","class_name":"MaxPooling2D","config":{"pool_size":[2,2],"padding":"valid","strides":[1,2],"data_format":"channels_last","name":"max_pooling2d_4","trainable":false},"inbound_nodes":[[["conv2d_4",0,0,{}]]]},{"name":"flatten_1","class_name":"Flatten","config":{"name":"flatten_1","trainable":false},"inbound_nodes":[[["max_pooling2d_4",0,0,{}]]]},{"name":"dropout_1","class_name":"Dropout","config":{"rate":0.25,"noise_shape":null,"seed":null,"name":"dropout_1","trainable":false},"inbound_nodes":[[["flatten_1",0,0,{}]]]},{"name":"dense_1","class_name":"Dense","config":{"units":2000,"activation":"relu","use_bias":true,"kernel_initializer":{"class_name":"VarianceScaling","config":{"scale":1,"mode":"fan_avg","distribution":"uniform","seed":null}},"bias_initializer":{"class_name":"Zeros","config":{}},"kernel_regularizer":null,"bias_regularizer":null,"activity_regularizer":null,"kernel_constraint":null,"bias_constraint":null,"name":"dense_1","trainable":false},"inbound_nodes":[[["dropout_1",0,0,{}]]]},{"name":"sequential_9","class_name":"Sequential","config":{"name":"sequential_9","layers":[{"class_name":"Dense","config":{"units":4,"activation":"softmax","use_bias":true,"kernel_initializer":{"class_name":"VarianceScaling","config":{"scale":1,"mode":"fan_avg","distribution":"normal","seed":null}},"bias_initializer":{"class_name":"Zeros","config":{}},"kernel_regularizer":null,"bias_regularizer":null,"activity_regularizer":null,"kernel_constraint":null,"bias_constraint":null,"name":"NewHeadDense","trainable":true,"batch_input_shape":[null,2000],"dtype":"float32"}}]},"inbound_nodes":[[["dense_1",0,0,{}]]]}],"input_layers":[["conv2d_1_input",0,0]],"output_layers":[["sequential_9",1,0]]},"keras_version":"tfjs-layers 1.3.1","backend":"tensor_flow.js"},"weightsManifest":[{"paths":["weights.bin"],"weights":[{"name":"NewHeadDense/kernel","shape":[2000,4],"dtype":"float32"},{"name":"NewHeadDense/bias","shape":[4],"dtype":"float32"},{"name":"conv2d_1/kernel","shape":[2,8,1,8],"dtype":"float32"},{"name":"conv2d_1/bias","shape":[8],"dtype":"float32"},{"name":"conv2d_2/kernel","shape":[2,4,8,32],"dtype":"float32"},{"name":"conv2d_2/bias","shape":[32],"dtype":"float32"},{"name":"conv2d_3/kernel","shape":[2,4,32,32],"dtype":"float32"},{"name":"conv2d_3/bias","shape":[32],"dtype":"float32"},{"name":"conv2d_4/kernel","shape":[2,4,32,32],"dtype":"float32"},{"name":"conv2d_4/bias","shape":[32],"dtype":"float32"},{"name":"dense_1/kernel","shape":[704,2000],"dtype":"float32"},{"name":"dense_1/bias","shape":[2000],"dtype":"float32"}]}]}
```

I have a trouble to run these codes using google colab. This codes i got from teachable machine using audio project( https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/ )
Please help me to fix the error.

This one is one is another meta.json file

```
{"tfjsSpeechCommandsVersion":"0.4.0","modelName":"TMv2","timeStamp":"2022-10-03T02:17:44.330Z","wordLabels":["Background Noise","Bell","Emergency alarm","Siren"]}
```

Comment: You did not say what's wrong, really. What error message do you get?

Comment: Please consider readability when formatting your questions. Putting large JSON data in a single line is not particularly helpful to the audience you want to attract.